# CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles"

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake, amazon-kinesis, mingw-w64

I am trying to use the C++ Producer SDK on Windows of AWS Kinesis, folowing the [steps of this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-win.html) I get this error running `cmake` .. on the `mingw64`:

```sh
$ cmake ..
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/gonpe/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

My working directory was `~/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-c`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Perhaps, the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141608/cmake-make-program-not-found) are helpful. When using MinGW, I don't think you should be using the `"Unix Makefiles"` generator. Instead, run CMake using: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`

Comment: @Gon Could you add some more information to your question? Your prompt looks like you are compiling from an MSys Bash shell. Is that the case? If yes, what happens when you execute "make --version" ? If no, what shell *are* you using?